# AppendRows in Storage Write API Golang gets stuck in a loop

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I am trying to send some data to BQ using Storage Write API.
I use this example:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api-batch

When my code is flat it works, but as soon as I put it into a loop it stucks forever at the second loop step and `res, err := ms.AppendRows(ctx, pfProto)`:

```golang
    results := []*managedwriter.AppendResult{}
    for i := 0; i < len(skus); i = i + PFStocksLimit {
        lim := i + PFStocksLimit
        if lim > len(skus)-1 {
            lim = len(skus) - 1
        }
        stocks := getStocks(skus[i:lim])
        pfProto := prepProto(gd, stocks)

        res, err := ms.AppendRows(ctx, pfProto)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("AppendRows call error: %v", err)
        }
        results = append(results, res)
}
```

Funny enough when I remove `results = append(results, res)` it works.
I do not understang what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that this is a bug for big data inserts, the issue is reported here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/6321

Solution: insert less rows at one time